# Counterexample to a given claim about prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, prime-gaps

Let $(x_{k})_{k≥2}$ and $(y_{k})_{k≥2}$ be two non constant sequences of strictly increasing positive integers such that $x_{k}>1,y_{k}>1$ for all $k≥2$.
I want to get a **counterexample** to the following **claim**:

**Claim**: *If there exist one positive integer $m≥2$ such that there is a prime number in the interval $(y_{m},x_{m}+y_{m})$, then for all $k≥m$ the interval $(y_{k},x_{k}+y_{k})$ contain a prime number*.

I have remark that if $x_{k}=(k+1)²- k²,y_{k}=k²$ then the problem is similar to the Legendre conjecture.

Comment: Have you tried looking at any sequence of small numbers to see when there are are are not primes in the intervals?

Comment: Consider the sequence $x_k = k$, $y_2=10$, $y_3=13$, $y_{k>3}=100+k$.

Comment: For general sequences there is very little relation between one of its terms and any further terms. You can take for instance $x_k=k$ and pick a sequence $y_k$ suitably, using the fact the gaps between primes can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: @Wojowu: I have remark that if $x_{k}=(k+1)²- k²,y_{k}=k²$ then the problem is similar to the legendre conjecture.

Comment: @Wojowu: You say: *For general sequences there is very little relation between one of its terms and any further terms.* Is a recurrence sequence solves this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x_2 = 2, y_2 = 22, x_3 = 3,y_3 = 25$$
$$x_k = x_{k-1} +1 \ and \ y_k = y_{k-1} +3 \ \forall \ k \ge 3$$
For k = 2 we have a prime 23 but for k = 3 there no prime in the range (25,28)

Comment: I was not the downvoter, but you may want to complement the answer by saying how you define $x_k,y_k$ for $k>3$. It will be a valid counterexample as long as they are increasing.

Comment: @Wojowu thanks for the suggestion